# IoC and Factory for C++ - Alternative to Microsoft Unity for c#

Tags: c++, inversion-of-control, factory

What is the most common use sturdy nugetpackage/library/framework for C++ that does pretty much the same as the C# library by Microsoft called Unity: http://unity.codeplex.com/ ?

The end result would look **something like this**:

```
class IProjectRepository
{
public:
    vector<Project> GetProjects() = 0;
}

class XMLProjectRepository : IProjectRepository
{
public:
    vector<Project> GetProjects()
    {
        return // implementation
    }
}

class Application
{
public:
    Application( shared_ptr<IProjectRepository> projectRepository ) 
    // Or however this would look... 
    // projectRepository would be an instance of whatever i have registered (see below)
    {
        auto projects = this.projectRepository.GetProjects();
    }
}
```

And in some startup area i would bind like this:

```
BinderFramework::Register<IProjectRepository, XMLProjectRepository>();What is the most common use sturdy nuget package/library for C++ that does pretty much the same as the C# library by Microsoft called Unity: http://unity.codeplex.com/
```

I have been looking for a while now, but can't quite find a nice complete and simple solution.

The idea is to use a well known framework rather than write my own flaky code.

Comment: There are IoC libraries for C++, but it's best to start with [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) (which means dependency injection without a library) and move to using a tool if it has proven to be effective.

Comment: It's required because I am making a multi platform solution. My core app code needs to work with interfaces... Plus i will also be able to test stuff.

Comment: Yes, you want to apply the Dependency Injection pattern and adhere to the Dependency Inversion Principle. But those are just patterns and principles. You don't need a tool to use those patterns. Please read [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be a bit late but you should give a look at [Hypodermic](https://github.com/ybainier/Hypodermic).

It's header only, it comes with a pretty cool Dsl plus it's been used for years in production environments.